# Firebase Storage images not working in Link Preview in iMessage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have a webpage that is generated on request by a functions.

Thinks a url like

`https://mywebsite.app/posts/postOne`, where on request I lookup `postOne` in Firestore, take some details about it and generate a page.

This works for the most part, but for images hosted in Firebase Storage, even with a token present, iMessage is unable to render a preview for this image. If I download the image, upload it to Imgur, and swap out the URLs, it works fine.

For example:

```
<meta property="go:title" content="Blog Post One">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/blogPosts%2Fposts%2FpostOne%2FpostOneCoverPhoto.png?alt=media&token=imageToken">
```

Will not render correctly, it will show the title and my pages favicon, but the image will not load.

Whereas if I take that exact image, upload it to Imgur, and generate a page like this:

```
<meta property="go:title" content="Blog Post One">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/myImgurImageId.jpg">
```

Everything renders correctly. Is this an issue with how Firebase handles the requests from clients like iMessage, or more likely a bug in iMessage?

Answer (score 1):

The framework you're using is adding `amp;` after `&` in a link to image, and this is the bug. I think instead of using regular variable in JavaScript, use:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="`${downloadURL}`">
```

In my case, it worked.

Comment: I think that was a mistake in how I wrote step post, but I can confirm on the actual page the &amp; is not present, and if I open the URL in my browser manually it downloads it

Comment: @Will Found another bug. XD You use property instead of name.

Comment: Not with Open Graph stuff, they use properties

Comment: @Will I see it works both ways, name and property. ;/ If it is not &amp; i don't know what it might be.